# SMALL-FACTOR is not NPC. Is the statement true or false?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np, co-np

Given the SMALL FACTOR problem where:

- INPUT: an integer N and an integer k
- OUTPUT: yes ⇐⇒ N has a prime factor ≤ k.

I know that SMALL-FACTOR problem ∈ in NP ∩ CO-NP.
If it were NP-Complete we would have that CO-NP=NP.
So how can I answer the above question?